# Problem in accessing a bean having request scope need in worker thread

Tags: spring, spring-boot, multithreading, executorservice

I have a rest controller when call comes to it main thread submit the request to the worker thread using executor service, in my code I have one bean which is of request based lets call it `Hello`
In my application I am injecting this bean through `ObjectFactory` not directly `Hello` in other service kind of lazy initialising.

Because worker thread will execute my application code and application will have this request bean dependency so we have to give it to worker thread that I am setting in worker thread like below
I am getting the context from main thread because spring has injected it already
`var context = RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();`
and while submitting the worker thread I am doing
`RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(context);`
and now worker thread is able to get request scope bean. till this code is working fine

**Problem:**

Now my main thread waits for 10 secs if response comes from worker thread it respond back to the client with 200Ok
other wise it just say we will give you the response shortly and worker thread is doing the thing in the background.
because master thread is finished and worker thread is still running and executing the code when it tries to get hello bean which is request based it doesn't get instead it gets below error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ScopeNotActiveException: Error creating bean with name 'hello': Scope 'request' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot ask for request attribute - request is not active anymore!
```

how can i fix this?
I want to have Hello Bean available to worker thread even after main thread exit

- tried cloning the context while setting in worker thread

Comment: Ummm... just read the values your background task is going to need before scheduling it? BTW why not use Spring Async instead? It would allow for a more seamless integration of background tasks

Comment: You could also store the values in a custom scope, though that's probably overkill

Comment: Please show some code what you are doing. I find it hard to read your question due to the long sentences and excessive wording.